# In what version was the (...) introduced in Lua functions as arguments?

Tags: lua, parameter-passing, argument-passing

This as the most simple example as I can imagine:

```
function NewPrint(...)
    print("printed:", ...)
end

NewPrint("Hi")
```

Please note, I haven't actually done Lua for a while, I might have missed some syntax.

Comment: The old `arg` table is equivalent to `{...}`. And `local a, b = arg[1], arg[2]` would be equivalent to `local a, b = ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Lua.org documentation](http://www.lua.org/versions.html) , it was Lua 5.1 .

> Lua 5.1 was released on 21 Feb 2006. Its main new features were a new module system, incremental garbage collection, **new mechanism for varargs**, new syntax for long strings and comments, mod and length operators, metatables for all types, new configuration scheme via luaconf.h, and a fully reentrant parser.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in function definition has been introduced in <s>Lua 5.0 ([manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#func-def))</s> [Lua 2.5](http://www.lua.org/versions.html#2.5) (thanks to Luiz for correcting me), but it required to use `arg` table when you wanted to access those varargs. This has been fixed in Lua 5.1, which allowed to use `...` notation for definitions and access to varargs.

Comment: vararg functions were introduced in Lua 2.5: see http://www.lua.org/versions.html#2.5 and the table in page 6 of the HOPL paper, http://www.lua.org/doc/hopl.pdf .

Comment: @lhf; thank you for the clarification! I didn't go that far and don't have experience with versions older than 5.0 ;).